# iOS UILabel subview sometimes shows up later than other subviews 

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uilabel

I have a strange bug where my UILabel, which is a subview of a custom object, doesn't show up until a few seconds later then all the other subviews.

Also, if the user touches the screen while the UILabel isn't visible, then the UILabel immediately becomes visible.

Has anyone faced this kind of weird behavior? Any pointers on how to fix it?

Thanks!

xcode 4.3.3, ios 5.0+, ARC

Answer (score 0):

It could be that it doesn't gets drawn with the rest of the objects (not sure why). Try calling `setNeedsDisplay` on the `UILabel` or its parent where appropriate, e.g. from `viewWillAppear`.